# Multitenancy with unknown dynamic data per tenant

Tags: php, postgresql, multi-tenant

I am working on a system, where among the requirements are:

1. PHP + PostgreSql
2. Multitenant system, using a single database for all the tenants (tenantId).
3. Each tenant's data is unknown, so they should have the flexibility to add whatever data they want:

   - e.g. for an accounts table,

   tenant 1 > account_no | date_created | due_date

   tenant 2 > account_holder | start_date | end_date | customer_name | ...

The only solution I can see for this case is using the key-value pair database structure:
    - e.g.

```
accounts table
            id  | tenant_id  | key          | value
            1   1             account_no    12345



accounts_data table
            account_id | key                | value
            1           date_created        01-01-2014
            1           due_date            30-02-2014
```

The draw backs I see for this approach in the long run:

```
- Monster queries
- Inefficient with large data
- Lots of coding to handle data validation, since no data types are there and everything is saved as string
- Filtering can be lots of work
```

Having that said, I would appreciate suggestions as well as if any other approach I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Warning, you're walking into the [inner platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) and [Enterprisey design](http://thedailywtf.com/Series/Feature_Articles.aspx).

Stop and back away slowly, then revisit your assumptions about *why* you have to do things this way.

Something has to give here; either:

- Use a schemaless free-form database for schemaless, free-form data;
- Allow tenant users to define useful schema for their data based on their needs; or
- Compromise with something like `hstore` or `json` storage

Please, please, please don't create a database within an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model of a database. [Developers everywhere in the world will cry](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Database-Changes-Done-Right.aspx) and your design will soon end up talked about on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. I know I am heading towards a beast of coding, queries and work. Things would have been easier if I could fix the columns to be same for all tenants, but my situation here, the tenants should have the flexibility to upload whatever data they want, and later on, process those data. Any thoughts on how I can accommodate different data sets/tenants into the db?

Comment: Btw, guess your link "Enterprisey design" didn't lead me to the intended page.

Comment: @nsk Dynamically `CREATE` and `ALTER` tables based on what they need, use `hstore` or `json` to store their rows, or use a schemaless database.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing "create and alter" tables on the fly, but, if the columns are different (naming/data-type/no of columns) for different tenants, what would i base my query on? e.g. "select [what] from tenant_account_table", how do i identify the [what]? any idea?

Comment: @nsk You need tables per-tenant if you take that approach.

Comment: yes, each tenant has its own tables, which i referred to with "tenant_account_table" as an example in my last comment. but how to write the logic and query that fits to all tenants? because if not, then i  would end up developing totally separate systems.

Comment: @nsk You'll need query generation to go with your tables if you insist on doing this in PostgreSQL with tables you `ALTER` to meet each user's needs. Again, bringing you rapidly back to the inner platform. If you don't want a schema, don't use a system designed around data schemas! I don't know how else to say this: You're about to try to use a chainsaw to make scrambled eggs. Wrong tool for the job. Square peg, round hole. Just. Don't. Do. This. Use `hstore` rows, use `json` rows, use XML if you like, or use something better suited to this job than PostgreSQL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46305/discussion-between-nsk-and-craig-ringer)

Comment: @nsk No, let's not. I won't go around in circles with you about this, I don't have the time or the energy. I've said what I have to say.